# SUM() giving error 'dict object' has no attribute 'SUM'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

My query `{{ SUM(something) }}` is giving an error.

HTML :

```
{% for stock in portfolio %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ stock.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ stock.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ "stock.SUM(shares)" }}</td>
                <td>{{ stock.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ stock.SUM(total) }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Query :

```
portfolio = db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT symbol, name, SUM(shares), price, SUM(total) FROM history GROUP BY name;")

return render_template("index.html", portfolio = portfolio)
```

`stock.SUM(shares)` and `stock.SUM(total)` are giving this error :

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'SUM'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by the following syntax:

```
<td>{{ stock['SUM(shares)'] }}</td>
<td>{{ stock['SUM(total)'] }}</td>
```

The 'dict object' error hinted that maybe a dict syntax could work, and it did.